# MPC HC toolbar in Dark Theme

Tags: media-player

MPC HC has a dark theme now, but it replaces the toolbar skin.
https://trac.mpc-hc.org/wiki/Toolbar_images

Can the toolbar skin be kept with dark theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be removed. Toolbar Skins page on the website is gone and the MPC-HC installer is updated with a flag not to show the toolbar selection menu. I am of the opinion that the toolbar skinning still works in non-dark mode, but more as an inherited functionality than intended one.

Answer (score 1):

Custom toolbars are working in both light and dark mode.

- **toolbar.bmp** for normal grayscale
- **toolbar_dark.bmp** for dark theme grayscale
- **color_toolbar.bmp** for normal colored
- **color_toolbar_dark.bmp** for dark colored

Also, you can use with either BMP, PNG or SVG file format

You should place them in installation dir (probably something like `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64` )